# Struggling with 'for' statement in Python

Tags: python, list

I have to write a program using Python, which should ask the user to enter integer numbers to compose a list of numbers. Then I have to check whether at least one number in this list is 3 digits long. How can I do that? I should use 'for' statement. I started this way:

```
numbers_list = []

while True: 
         try: 
             n = int(input("Enter an integer (press ENTER to end the program): "))
         except ValueError: 
                break 
         else: numbers_list.append(n)
```

And then I tried to do this way, but it didn`t work:

```
num = False 
for num in numbers: 
        if len(num) == 3: 
               num = True 
             break 
print(num)
```

The answer should be: E.g. input = [1, 101, 2000], then output would be True; if input = [1,2,3], then output would be False

Comment: your variable is named `number_list` above yet you call it `numbers` below. And no, you cannot call `len` on a number, suggest using `len(str(number))`

Comment: You use the variable `num` for multiple purposes, so you will never output `False`.

Comment: Thank you guys, I will change the code and try to make it work.

Comment: Thanks, Antti! The porblem was in 'len' function. I changed it a bit and now it works. :)

Comment: But you're code return true only if any one of the element contain exact three digits.

Comment: @MirelK did you mean exact three digits or atleast three digits?

Comment: Rather at least one number should be 3 digits long, then the program will output True.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use [`any`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#any) function to return a bool value if any one element in the given list satisfies a particular condition.

```
numbers_list = []

while True: 
    try: 
        n = int(input("Enter an integer (press ENTER to end the program): "))
    except ValueError: 
        break 
    else: numbers_list.append(n)


print(any(len(str(i))>2 for i in numbers_list))
```

It returns `true` if any one element in the list has the length greater than 2.

To return true if an element has exact three digits, then change the above `any` statement to,

```
print(any(len(str(i))==3 for i in numbers_list))
```

Comment: Thank you for your help. I got the code working. Yei! :)

Comment: I'm curious.  Why convert the number to a string and use `len`?  What's wrong with `> 99`  or `99 < i < 1000`?

Comment: object of type string has the len function. So you need to convert the interger to string in-order to find it's length.

Comment: yep, you could do like above , but converting it to string is the preferred way to go.

Comment: Converting to string will see two-digit negative numbers as three symbols. I might go with `any(100<=i<=999 or -100>=i>=-999 for i in numbers)`. Note that [comparisons](https://docs.python.org/2/reference/expressions.html#not-in) can be chained. It is also more costly to create a string representation than do an integer compare, though that will be insignificant here.